# How to set session timeout / expiry time in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, session-cookies, session-timeout, aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP.NET Zero version 7 of ASP.NET Core, MVC and jQuery project.

I am trying to set session timeout / expiry time to automatically log out from the application when the application is idle for some time. Can anybody please let me know how to do this?

In ASP.NET Zero version 8, they are providing this configuration at User Management settings.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET Zero 7.x are you on?

Answer (score 7):

## ASP.NET Core MVC

Session expiry for MVC is provided via cookie by ASP.NET Core, independent of ASP.NET Zero.

Call `ConfigureApplicationCookie` after `IdentityRegistrar.Register` in **Startup.cs**:

```cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);                  // No change
    AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration); // No change

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
    {
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        o.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

    // ...
}
```

The defaults from [ASP.NET Core v2.2.8 CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L30-L36](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.8/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L30-L36):

```cs
public CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
    ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    SlidingExpiration = true;
    Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents();
}
```

## ASP.NET Zero (for ASP.NET Core)

ASP.NET Zero v7.2.0+ provides:

- for MVC: frontend configuration and countdown modal.
  Docs: [aspnet-core-mvc/v7.2.0/Features-Mvc-Core-Tenant-Settings#user-management](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-mvc/v7.2.0/Features-Mvc-Core-Tenant-Settings#user-management)
- for Angular: implementation of session timeout via token, frontend configuration and countdown modal.
  Docs: [aspnet-core-angular/v7.2.0/Features-Angular-Tenant-Settings#user-management](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-angular/v7.2.0/Features-Angular-Tenant-Settings#user-management)

Comment: what means SlidingExpiration  ?